# How i can use Junit to test a Singleton EJB that return a MongoClient?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, junit, ejb, jboss-arquillian

I have to test with JUnit a simple Singleton EJB that return a MongoClient. 
I think I can try with Arquillian.

With this code I obtain an Java.lang.AssertionError because EJB isn't injected by the container. Where I'm wrong?

- EJB class:

  ```
  @Stateless
  @Singleton
  @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
  public class MongoClientProviderBean {

      private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MongoClientProviderBean.class);
      private MongoClient mongoClient = null;

      @Lock(LockType.READ)
      public MongoClient getMongoClient() {
          return mongoClient;
      }

      @PostConstruct
      public void init() {
          try {
              String address = "mongo-host";
              int port = 27017;
              //TODO: inject del indirizzo e porta
              mongoClient = new MongoClient(address, port);
              logger.info("Inizializzato mongoclient ("+address+", "+port+")");
          } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

      @PreDestroy
      public void tearDown() {
          mongoClient.close();
          logger.info("Mongoclient chiuso");
      }
  }
  ```
- Test Class:

  ```
  @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
  public class MongoClientProviderBeanTest {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MongoClientProviderBean.class);
  @EJB
  MongoClientProviderBean mongoClientProviderBean;
  @Deployment
  public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
      return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
              .addClasses(MongoClientProviderBean.class, MongoClient.class)
              .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
  }

  @Test
  public void getMongoClient() throws Exception {
      assertNotNull(mongoClientProviderBean);
      /*
      dummy test
       */
      mongoClientProviderBean.getMongoClient();
    }

  }
  ```
- Part of POM:

  ```
  [...]
  <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
              <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
              <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
              <scope>import</scope>
              <type>pom</type>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
          <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      [...]
  </dependencies>
  [...]
  ```

I also tried with Wildfly managed container, but I obtain this exception:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.LifecycleException: Could not start container

at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.managed.ManagedDeployableContainer.startInternal(ManagedDeployableContainer.java:168)
at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.start(CommonDeployableContainer.java:123)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:199)
[...]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYLNCHR0001: The path 'null' does not exist
at org.wildfly.core.launcher.Environment.validateWildFlyDir(Environment.java:313)
at org.wildfly.core.launcher.AbstractCommandBuilder.validateWildFlyDir(AbstractCommandBuilder.java:652)
```

And JUnit can't start the container.

Comment: In your stacktrace for WildFly it clearly says that you have adapter misconfigured -validateWildFlyDir fails with `null` path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weld alone won't inject EJB. Perhaps you can try with [ejb-cdi-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit) that extends weld, so that ejbs are injected like normal beans.

Comment: Thanks for reply ;). Maybe i don't understand how it works this library but in this example (http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/) EJB is injected with Weld. How it's possible?

Comment: The EJB-Servers built on Weld extend that by injecting special extensions. These extensions allow it to change the behaviour so that transactionmanagers are used, EJBs are injected, ... That's the cause why weld-se is not enough. Sadly the only embeddable EJB-Container is tomee which is not based on Weld. My goal was it, to provide something, that allows functional tests without having to start an ejb-server with its compicated configuration, hundreds of threads, complicated datasource and jms definition.

Comment: You need to start wildfly in managed mode. There is also an example in the shown project: [ejb-cdi-unit-arq](https://github.com/1and1/ejb-cdi-unit/tree/master/ejb-cdi-unit-arq). But there are numerous other examples in the net, how to start wildfly inside arquillian.

Comment: This is not correct. Weld-ee-embedded is a container supporting EJB injection https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Weld+EE+1.1+-+Embedded. However, I would go with Wildfly for the tests.

Comment: @bartosz.majsak interesting, I was convinced, that weld-se per se does not support it. How do I activate it since, I went length to make it work using my own Extension. Normally at-EJB annotated fields stay null. aahh, I have to look into this, weld-se and weld...embedded are different here, I presumed otherwise. Thanks

Comment: @bartosz.majsak the documentation is one thing, in reality arquillian forces those fields to be null. Even using an extension does not help, that only works in weld-se without arquillian.

Comment: @aschoerk can you share reproducer project?